# Not explicitly saying `return` gives error: `match` arms have incompatible types

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust.

The following function:

```rust
async fn create(body: String) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let j = match serde_json::from_str::<CreationJSON>(&body) {
        Ok(j) => j,
        Err (_) => (
            StatusCode::UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
            "body is invalid".to_string(),
        ),
    };
    println!("{:?}", j.record_stringified);

    (
        StatusCode::CREATED,
        "created".to_string(),
    )
}
```

gives error:

```text
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
   --> src/main.rs:128:20
    |
126 |       let j = match serde_json::from_str::<CreationJSON>(&body) {
    |               ------------------------------------------------- `match` arms have incompatible types
127 |           Ok(j) => j,
    |                    - this is found to be of type `CreationJSON`
128 |           Err (_) => (
    |  ____________________^
129 | |             StatusCode::UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
130 | |             "body is invalid".to_string(),
131 | |         ),
    | |_________^ expected `CreationJSON`, found `(StatusCode, String)`
    |
    = note: expected struct `CreationJSON`
                found tuple `(axum::http::StatusCode, std::string::String)`
```

However, if I add a "return" to the `Err` arm, then it works fine:

```rust
async fn create(body: String) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let j = match serde_json::from_str::<CreationJSON>(&body) {
        Ok(j) => j,
        Err (_) => return (
            StatusCode::UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
            "body is invalid".to_string(),
        ),
    };
    println!("{:?}", j.record_stringified);

    (
        StatusCode::CREATED,
        "created".to_string(),
    )
}
```

Why do I need to add the `return` in the `Err` arm? I thought a function with no semi-colon was supposed to automatically return in Rust?

Comment: If you don't `return`, you're telling it _to assign the tuple to `j`_, not to return the tuple as the function's value.

Comment: (Think about it: If _every_ statement without a `return` keyword did an implicit return -- as opposed to just the _final_ statement -- you couldn't have more than one statement in a function! So the interpretation of the language's behavior that the question is premised on doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. When you explain it that way, it makes complete sense and my thinking seems silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` returns from the function. If you don't use the `return` keyword, then it'll "return" from the statement. In your first example, you're trying to assign the tuple to the variable `j`, while in the second you return from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Note for why latter code compiles: in Rust, the type of return value from each arm must be same after [type coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) is invoked. `return` statement has type of [`!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) (never type), which is coerced into `CreationJson`.